# Change xaml grid background in windows 8 phone c#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, colors, background-color

I would like to change the background of the grid in C# code but there is an error while doing so.

Here is the code:

```
gd.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Aqua);
```

The error says I am missing an assembly reference as the namespace "Colors" does not exist.

Or is there another way to change the background colour of a windows phone 8 theme colour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already an answer to this question. I also had issues with the background color and this thread resolved it for me.
URL: [Changing color of grid in C# (Windows Phone 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633092/changing-color-of-grid-in-c-sharp-windows-phone-8)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your `Namespace of Colors`. It should be ***System.Windows.Media***.

This is the demo using **Colors**:

```
gd.Background = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush
                         (System.Windows.Media.Colors.Green);
```

Another way, we can use **Color** with **FromArgb** method:

```
gd.Background = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush
                         (System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF, 0x00));
```

we should set `A R G B` for it, it's from 0x00 to 0xFF.

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
gd.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray);
```